# Check textfield text while editing

Tags: ios, swift, regex, uitextfield

I have a `textField` which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to keep track of what the user is typing in. If the text inputs matches one of the criteria below the textfield the "x" should change to a "checkImage".

I already have a `TextFieldDidChange` method for this:

```
@objc func passwordTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text == "" {
            self.eyeButton.isHidden = true
        }else {
            self.eyeButton.isHidden = false
        }

}
```

**Problem:**

How do I check a text for:
**1.** at least 1 uppercase letter + 1 lowercase letter 
**2.** at least 1 digit
**3.** at least length 8

I also check the password strength afterwards with this method:

```
static func isPasswordValid(_ password : String) -> Bool {

    /*
    ^                         Start anchor
    (?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])        Ensure string has two uppercase letters.
    (?=.*[!@#$&*])            Ensure string has one special case letter.
    (?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])        Ensure string has two digits.
    (?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]) Ensure string has three lowercase letters.
    .{8}                      Ensure string is of length 8.
    $                         End anchor.
    */

    let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.*[A-Z]).(?=.*[0-9]).(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$")
    return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
}
```

But the user should also get "realtime" feedback wether or not is password is matching the 3 criteria.

Let me know if my question if unclear or if you need some more info. Grateful for every help :)

Answer (score 2):

That's a tricky one, but you're on the right track.

> I also check the password strength afterwards with this method

It's not clear when you are calling `isPasswordValid(:)` but this needs to be done after the text field changes, ideally in the `passwordTextFieldDidChange(:)` function.

Bonus: You can move the updating of the eye button into a separate function to aid in readability.

```
@objc func passwordTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.updateEyeButton(show: !textField.isEmpty)
    self.validate(password: textField.text)
}
```

There are a lot of different ways you can accomplish this task but this one should be pretty self explanatory, feel free to ask if you need further clarification.

You will need to separate the validation of each of your requirements.  In your current `isPasswordValid(:)` function, you check all the requirements together, which makes it impossible to determine which one passed/failed.

What you can do is create a separate struct to validate the requirements, in this case we named it `PasswordValidator`. This struct validates whether a given password matches your requirements and if not, returns the missing requirements to you.  Once you have an array of the missing requirements, you can act on each one (in your case changing the icon for each one).

Something like this (untested):

```
private struct PasswordValidator {

     private enum Result {
        case valid
        case invalid([Validator.Requirement])
     }

     private enum Requirement: String {
         case minimumOneUppercaseOneLowercase = "(?=.*[A-Z]).(?=.*[a-z])"
         case minimumOneDigit = "(?=.*[0-9])"
     }

      static func validate(password: String) -> PasswordValidator.Result {

          let missingRequirements = [Requirement]()

          if !evaluate(password: password, requirement: .minimumOneUppercaseOneLowercase) {
              missingRequirements.append(.minimumOneUppercaseOneLowercase)
          }

          if !evaluate(password: password, requirement: .minimumOneDigit) {
              missingRequirements.append(.minimumOneDigit)
          }

          if missingRequirements.isEmpty == false {
              return .invalid(missingRequirements)
          }

          return .valid
      }

      private static func evaluate(password: String, requirement: PasswordValidator.Requirement) -> Bool {
          let predicateString = "^\(requirement.rawValue)$"
          let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", predicateString)
          return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
      }
  }
```

As you can see each of the `PasswordValidator.Requirement` enum cases have an associated value containing the predicate (very untested!)

Now in your view controller, you can have a simple function to handle the validation result (called from your `passwordTextFieldDidChange(:)` function:

```
private func validate(password: String) {

        let validationResult = PasswordValidator.validate(password: password)

        switch validationResult {
        case .valid:
            // All should be checkmarks
            // self.updateIcons(missingRequirements: nil)
        case .invalid(let missingRequirements):
            // Change the icons
            // self.updateIcons(missingRequirements: missingRequirements)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will test this in the next couple of days! Will let you know if it works or not. Really appreciate your answer, thanks!